# Enable Facebook Connect for logging in my mobile website

Tags: facebook, mobile

I want to enable **Facebook connect**  for login in my mobile website.

How should i go about it?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the guide in the Facebook developer documentation. You can see it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login.